# Eval, rpar and rseq -- any benefit?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I'm learning parallelism in Haskell. I've seen this code:

```
runEval $ do
  a <- rpar (f x)
  b <- rpar (f y)
  rseq a
  rseq b
  return (a,b)
```

What's the difference between it and this in terms of performance and overhead?

```
let a = f x
let b = f y
(a, b)
```

that is, without using `Eval` at all. For me, the 2nd one has the same performance and less overhead.

Answer (score 6):

It depends entirely on what `f` does. If `f` takes a long time for your system to compute, and your system has a spare CPU core, then the parallel version will finish faster.

If `f` is something tiny like `f n = n + 1` then *of course* the standard single-threaded version will be faster. The overhead of creating a Haskell thread is fairly low, but it's not **that** low. (And if you've only got a single execution context then there's no point anyway, of course).

Note that the first version *always* has more "overhead", if we define overhead as "work the system does that's not directly related to computing your result". But if you get to evaluate`f x` and `f y` in parallel, you might finish faster even though the system has "wasted" some of its execution resources on the overhead. We might approximate the parallel version's run time as:

```
maximum(time for f x, time for f y)  +  overhead
```

And the standard version's run time as:

```
time for f x  +  time for f y
```

So the parallel version is only worth it if the *smaller* of the two `f` calls takes conclusively more time than the parallelisation overhead.

Of course in reality it could be much more complicated. One such issue: if `f x` and `f y` share references to the same thunks, then the standard sequential version fully shares the work, while the parallel version might accidentally waste time having both threads execute the thunks. In particular if most of the work of `f x` and `f y` is *actually* reducing thunks to get `f` ready to apply, then you're not "really" parallelising this work at all (instead more-or-less racing two threads to see which finishes first).

Ultimately you need to use measurements and judgement to decide where to apply parallelism. It's not something you can add blindly and automatically get a benefit (otherwise the compiler would do it for you).

But it certainly **won't** give you any benefit if you try to run two really trivial computations in parallel. If you're just playing around with parallelism to get a feel for how it works, try to write a function `f` that does enough work such that your second version takes at least a couple of seconds to run, and then see if the parallel version is faster.

Comment: `and your system has a spare CPU core, then the parallel version will finish faster.` -- but we wait for them both to finish anyway by calling `rseq`, therefore even if the 1st one finished fast, it still has to wait for the 2nd one afterwards. so what's the benefit on calling them in parallel instead of sequentially?

Comment: @Daaka The benefit is the the shorter one's runtime proceeds **while the longer one is running**. So you only have to wait the time the longer one needs, not the longer one **plus** the shorter one. Again, to be worth doing, you usually expect **both** of them to take a reasonable amount of time. Say, 6 seconds and 4 seconds. If you run them sequentially, it takes 10 seconds. If you run them in parallel, it only takes 6 (plus the overhead, which isn't perceptible in human time).

Comment: Concrete numbers: if you have two jobs that 30 and 40 minutes, the parallel version takes 40 minutes plus overhead. The sequential version takes 70 minutes. Say your first call to `rseq` is for the 40-minute job. That takes 40 minutes, but the *next* call returns immediately, because that job has been done for 10 minutes. If the calls to `rseq` are reversed, the first one take 30 minutes, and the second one takes an additional 10 minutes (since that is all that's left of the 40-minute job). Either way, the combined running time for both calls to `rseq` is 40 minutes.